# How to compile openvas-smb

Tags: compilation, openvas

i'm trying to build openvas-smb bin for Almalinux 9.2.
One of the requirements is heimdal-gssapi. So i build this package and intall it.

When trying to compile openvas, it fails with this error :

```
-- Install prefix: /usr/local
-- Checking for module 'heimdal-gssapi>=1.6.0'
--   Package 'heimdal-gssapi', required by 'virtual:world', not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:556 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:778 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:151 (pkg_check_modules)
```

I change CMakeLists.txt to specify the heimdal lib location, ti try to add these two lines but it do not seems to have any effect.

include_directories("/usr/heimdal/include")
add_subdirectory (/usr/heimdal/include)

I'm not familiar to cmake. Can someone confirm that external library must be imported by one of these line or explain out how to do it ?

thanks

EDIT:
Problem solved, i post solution here :
https://github.com/greenbone/openvas-smb/issues/42